# PHP foreach MVC Warning

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have been trying to learn some PHP. I am trying to print out the contents of my database. I have been following a tutorial but have run into the following warning that I cannot shift at all.

**Warning**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Lab10/app/views/View.php on line 20
```

**Foreach Loop**

```
$HTMLItemList = "";
foreach ( $this->model->itemList as $row ) 
    $HTMLItemList .= "<li><strong>" . $row ["title"] . ": </strong>" . $row ["price"] . "<blockquote>" . $row ["description"] . "</blockquote></li>";
$HTMLItemList = "<ul>" . $HTMLItemList . "</ul>";
```

**Model->itemList**

```
public$itemList=null;
public function prepareItemList () {
    $this->ItemList = $this->itemsDAO->getItems ();
}
```

**itemsDAO->getItems()**

```
public function getItems () {
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT *";
    $sqlQuery .= "FROM items";
    $sqlQuery .= "ORDER BY items.title;";

    $result = $this->getDbManager () -> executeSelectQuery ( $sqlQuery );
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: your item list is empty or bad type, are you sure that you are calling prepareItemList() before foreach and that itemList is array ?

Comment: the above code is all I have been doing, should I be calling the prepareItemList() a few lines before my foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, i think. prepareItemList() must be called before accessing itemList

Comment: Whats your model name and you have been calling `itemList`  instead of `prepareItemList` and as well you have lots of typo within your code you

Comment: public$itemList=null; needs a space after public

Comment: `itemList` != `ItemList`

Comment: I have set the itemList as null and then function called prepareItemList() which sets the itemList string as the result, @zdeniiik how would I go about calling it before?

Comment: In the code above prepareItem List() isn't called. And as TiiJ7 says; be careful about case sensitive names, itemList is not the same as ItemList

Comment: I tried the loop as `foreach ( $this->model->prepareItemList as $row )` but it still didnt work

Comment: I add an answer, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pls

```
$this->model->prepareItemList();
$HTMLItemList = "";
foreach ( $this->model->itemList as $row ) 
   $HTMLItemList .= "<li><strong>" . $row ["title"] . ": </strong>" . $row ["price"] . "<blockquote>" . $row ["description"] . "</blockquote></li>";
```

and

```
public $itemList=null;
public function prepareItemList () {
    $this->itemList = $this->itemsDAO->getItems ();
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You must first call the prepare function and then use itemList, otherwise itemList is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

The variable that PHP tried to iterate through on the foreach is just not an array. Try to `var_dump()` it to check.

You can set `array()` as default value for `itemList` attribute on your model, so that if your initializer method is not called, your foreach will not raise a warning.

**The error you made here** is that your `getItems` methods is called and it puts result on `ItemList` attribute and not `itemList`. Mind the case !

Just replace

```
public function prepareItemList() {
  $this->ItemList = $this->itemsDAO->getItems();
}
```

by

```
public function prepareItemList() {
  $this->itemList = $this->itemsDAO->getItems();
}
```

and it will works.

Comment: thanks for the reply but after the changes I am still getting the same error

Comment: Put some `var_dump()` on your code to know what's going on, we can't debug it for you.